# Accessing data from a count method in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am returning information from a DataFrame using the count method this way :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(csv_file)

for i in df['OPTION'].unique():
   count = df.loc[df['OPTION'] == i].count
   print count
```

this returns:

> DatetimeIndex: 4641 entries, 2014-01-08 02:02:05.740845 to 2014-01-08 02:58:56.405287
>
> Data columns (total 3 columns):
>
> OPTION    4641 non-null values
>
> SELL      4641  non-null values
>
> BUY       4641 non-null values
>
> dtypes: float64(2), object(1)>

Which is the kind of information I'm after, but I would like to access data like the count (4641 in this example) or "non-null values" in my code, not just print them out. How should I access this kind of data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you are effectively creating `groups` of data. So this is better served as following.

```
grouped = df.groupby('OPTION')
```

Next, you wish to get the specific groups from this `grouped` object. So you iterate over groups, extract the counts (which is basically the length of the index), extract specific columns (for eg. SELL)

```
for name, group in grouped:
    print("Option name: {}".format(name))
    # Count of entries for this OPTION
    print("Count: {}".format(len(group.index)))
    # Accessing specific columns, say SELL
    print("SELL for this option\n")
    print(group["SELL"])
    # Summary for SELL for this option
    print("Summary\n")
    print(group["SELL"].describe())
```

A good reference for aggregate-split-combine is the official [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html) docs.
Quoting from the same.

```
By “group by” we are referring to a process involving one or more of the following steps
Splitting the data into groups based on some criteria
Applying a function to each group independently
Combining the results into a data structure
```